# WPF Validation On StartDate and EndDate (StartDate less than Enddate)

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpftoolkit

I am achieving a function "WPF Validation On StartDate and EndDate (StartDate  less than Enddate)", I write code in code behind to throw an exception if the EndDate is less than the StartDate, and now it works. But I met a problem about the validation on StartDate and EndDate fileds. Since these two properties are compulsory fields in my database, the Save button should be disabled unless you fill these two fields. But now StartDate and EndDate fileds are not compulsory. I am attaching my codes. Can you please spare a few minutes to look at my code and provide some suggestions? Many thanks.

**Code Behind**

```
public partial class OrganisationTypeSView : UserControl
{

    OrganisationTypeViewModel _dataContext = new OrganisationTypeViewModel();
    public OrganisationTypeSView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

     this.DataContext = _dataContext;

        _dataContext.AccountStartDate = DateTime.Now;
        _dataContext.AccountEndDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1);
        this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(OrganisationTypeSView_Loaded);
    }

    void OrganisationTypeSView_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

}
```

**xmal**

```
<WPFToolkit:DatePicker Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" Name="dpAccStart" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
        SelectedDate="{Binding AccountStartDate, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True}" />

<WPFToolkit:DatePicker Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="5" Name="dpAccEnd" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
        SelectedDate="{Binding AccountEndDate, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True}"/>
```

**ViewModel**

```
    private DateTime? _AccountStartDate;
    private DateTime? _AccountEndDate;        
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged; 

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Account Start Date is a required field.")]
    public DateTime? AccountStartDate
    {
        get { return _AccountStartDate; }
        set
        {

            if (_AccountStartDate != DateTime.MinValue && AccountEndDate != DateTime.MinValue)
            {

                if (value > _AccountEndDate)
                {                        
                    MessageBox.Show("Start date must be less than End date");
                    value = this.AccountStartDate;                    
                }
             }
            _AccountStartDate = value;

           if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("AccountStartDate"));
            }
        }
    }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Account End Date is a required field.")]
    public DateTime? AccountEndDate
    {
        get { return _AccountEndDate; }
        set
        {
            if (_AccountStartDate != DateTime.MinValue && AccountEndDate != DateTime.MinValue)
            {
                if (_AccountStartDate > value)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("End date must be after Start date");
                    value = this.AccountEndDate;
                }
            }

            _AccountEndDate = value;

            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("AccountEndDate"));
            }
      }
    }
```

Comment: What is your final aim - to make Save dissabled, while DataPickers are empty? Why you don't use commands then?

Comment: Hi voo. Thanks a lot for your quick reply. My final aim is to make Save dissabled while Datepickers are empty, and also the StartDate should be less than EndDate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by removing the codes "_dataContext.AccountStartDate = DateTime.Now; _dataContext.AccountEndDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1);" in code behind. Since I give an initial date for the StartDate and EndDate field, it gets the initial date automatically, so the save button will be activated.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a validation rule based on completness of your bound class.
Let your ViewModel implement the INotifyDataErrorInfo interface and implement GetErrors, HasErrors, etc.

Finally add

```
ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True
```

to the binding.

This allows you to check for consistency of the entire model, not just single properties.

Comment: Hi Samuel. Could you please clarify that or provide a sample? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is it acceptable for you to mark the form on start as not-validated? Then I would provider a better solution. Furthermore remove the Nullable Type from your View DateTime Properties as they are mandatory now

Answer (score 0):

I suppose besides of validation you should use Save command both with CanExecute handler, which would check the values of dpAccStart and AccountEndDate, something like this:

```
    private DateTime? _AccountStartDate;
    private DateTime? _AccountEndDate; 

    //Your code

    RelayCommand _saveCommand;
    public ICommand SaveCmd
    {
        get
        {
            if (_saveCommand == null)
                _saveCommand = new RelayCommand(ExecuteSaveCommand, CanExecuteCommand);
            return _saveCommand;
        }
    }

    private void ExecuteSaveCommand(object parameter)
    {
        //your saving logic
    }

    private bool CanExecuteCommand(object parameter)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_AccountStartDate) ||
            string.IsNullOrEmpty(_AccountEndDate))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
```

Then in XAML you can  assign your SaveCmd command save button:

```
   <Button Command="{Binding SaveCmd}">
```

After this the WPF will automaticly check the values of of dates making it enabled or disabled according to conditions of you CanExecute handler

Comment: I do use the command. My code is as follows:                     #region Add
        private ICommand updateCommand;
        public ICommand UpdateCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (updateCommand == null)
                {
                    updateCommand = new RelayCommand(this.UpdateExecute);
                }
                return updateCommand;
            }
        }

        private void UpdateExecute()
        {
                this.Update();
        }

        #endregion

Comment: @DanielXu You don't have canExecute in your command. Add CanExecuteCommand to your code

Comment: When I add the CanExecuteCommand, THE ERROR is "The best overloaded method match for string.IsNullOrEmpty has some invalid arguments". Then I change the code to                                                       
        private bool CanExecuteCommand(object parameter)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_AccountStartDate.ToString()) ||
                string.IsNullOrEmpty(_AccountEndDate.ToString()))
                return false;
            return true;
        }
No errors, but the Save button still be activated while StartDate and EndDate fileds empty

Comment: @DanielXu did you attach the CanExecuteCommand to your RelayCommand in constructor?

Comment: RelayCommand updateCommand;
            public ICommand UpdateCommand
            {
                get
                {
                    if (updateCommand == null)
                        updateCommand = new RelayCommand(UpdateExecute, CanExecuteCommand);
                    return updateCommand;
                }
            }                   private void UpdateExecute(object parameter)
            {
                this.Update();
            }       I got errors in updateCommand = new RelayCommand(UpdateExecute, CanExecuteCommand): cannot convert from 'method group' to 'System.Action'

Comment: see excample http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/d3b07cce-841e-4f90-8e00-f8c5f6ccc01b/relaycommand-and-canexecute. You should probably do something wrong in publishing the CanExecuteCommand.

Comment: Hi Voo, I fixed the problem by removing the codes "_dataContext.AccountStartDate = DateTime.Now;
        _dataContext.AccountEndDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1);" in code behind. Since I give an initial date for the StartDate and EndDate field, it gets the initial date automatically, so the save button will be activated. But thanks a lot for your reply.

Comment: @DanielXu Welcome to SO :) Glad if it was useful